Poisson regression given multiple predictors on a repeating ID variable
I was wondering how a poisson regression would work given my dataset which describes a series of zip codes stratified by age groups, gender and death counts.
The regression would use death counts as the dependent and the zip code, age groups and gender as predictors.
The problem is that there are multiple rows per same zip code that I’m not sure how to account for in the poisson regression model. Do I have to rearrange the dataset?


Does a row correspond to a death count in a zip x age group x gender bucket in some fixed period of time? What do you want your model to accomplish in the end?

Hi Dimitriy, yes each row corresponds to a death count in a zip x age group x gender bucket. The data is not complete (still waiting for time period data in years), but eventually, the goal is to use a poisson regression model to generate mortality rates. The issue is that the "zip x" is going to be the same for alot of the rows since each zip code has several age ranges and each age range is additionally stratified into male and female death counts. Is it still possible to run a poisson regression using death counts as the dependent and zip, age range, and gender code as predictors?

Do you plan to forecast future death by age and gender for the same set of zipcodes? Do you have a count of people at risk in each bucket?

There are roughly 30K ZIP codes in the US, though not all of these have people in them who are at risk of dying. Let's say you have 20K ZIPs with people at risk your data in your data. You seem to have $T\ge 2$ years of data according to your screenshot. There are $2$ genders and $K\ge 4$ age groups.
That gives you ~(20K * T * 2 * K) rows and at least ~(20K + T + 2 + K - 1*4) parameters to estimate given your proposed specification (and even more if you want to add some interactions to get a richer model). I assume the population at risk is used as the exposure variable, so the coefficient is constrained to 1 and does not count here. An ordinary Poisson will probably choke here, given the number of parameters. If you have a sample of ZIPs, things may work better.
There are two options to make this feasible with many ZIPs:

Include fixed effects at a higher level of geography since that is the biggest culprit. State or region should work, but something less coarse may work too. Do this if you need statistical inference, like error bars around your prediction, or want to interpret your coefficients. This is complicated because ZIPs aren't polygons and don't always recognize state or other administrative boundaries. You can assign the ZIP to the geo unit where most people reside as an approximation. The easiest thing would be to aggregate to the first few digits of the five-digit ZIP.

Apply regularization to all/some variables to eliminate parameters. Do this if you just want to predict deaths or death rates. I would probably try the penalized coefficients for predictions, but sometimes, the postselection (unpenalized) coefficients work as well or better. You can use a holdout set to pick. I would start with a simple model: population as exposure, time, age, and gender dummies, maybe age x gender interactions (unpenalized) while penalizing the ZIP code dummies. Add additional complexity (variables and interactions) once the basic model is running.


The fact that ZIP codes appear multiple times is not a problem for the coefficients. Variables can have fewer distinct values than the number of observations. It does create a problem for standard errors in (1), so I would cluster the SEs by the geo unit you settle on (or higher, like state) level.
